# How to set iolib timeout

Tags: common-lisp

I'm using IOLIB with this code to resolve a hostname:

```
(sockets:address-to-string (sockets:lookup-hostname name))
```

I works, but the functions does not take any timeout paramenter, and i cannot figure out how to set these using socket options.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not easy to find (in particular, this is not documented), but following the chain of calls from `lookup-hostname` (<kbd>M-.</kbd> in Emacs), you can see your code eventually calls `dns-query`:

```
(defun dns-query (name &key (type :a) (search *dns-search-domain*)
                  (nameservers *dns-nameservers*) decode
                  (repeat *dns-repeat*) (timeout *dns-timeout*))
  ...)
```

The timeout argument defaults to a special variable `iolib/sockets::*dns-timeout*`, which is globally bound to 10. You then only need to bind it around your code to set a different timeout:

```
(let ((iolib/sockets::*dns-timeout* 1))
  ...)
```

The variable is not exported, but `dns-query` is, maybe it is better to call that function directly.

```
CL-USER> (iolib:dns-query "http://example.com" :timeout 0.0001)
NIL
CL-USER> (iolib:dns-query "http://example.com" :timeout 1)

#<DNS RESPONSE Id: 61273, Question: #(#<"http://example.com." A IN>) Flags: :OP/S :RD :RA :NAME-ERROR, Sections: QD(1) AN(0) NS(1) AD(0)>
```